# updating Notes document(s) via java

Tags: java, xpages

I am re-writing a Domino application with `XPages`. I have setup a basic CRUD implementation with help of Java classes. I am now at the point that I am creating/editing documents.

Since I am not so familiar in this area my code for now only worked with formats like text and date.

Where can I find examples how to work with other formats like multiple value fields, rich text, attachments, names, authors?

I assume I cannot cover every type of field via `getItemValue(String)` and `replaceItemValue`, or can I?

Comment: Lotus Notes Designer help has many examples of code. What exactly are you trying to accomplish and get a problem with it ?

Comment: to open Lotus Notes Designer, start Notes Designer, or open a Notes database in Designer via context menu, and select from menu Help - Help Contents. Make sure you are opening help contents from the designer, not the client. Otherwise you will get Notes client help, instead of Notes Designer help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use Views wherever I can as I believe it is quicker than getting the document. It can be a little unwieldy though if you have lots of columns.

So using dates you need to convert from Notes DateTime to a Java Date.

**Getting**

account.setDateExpiry1(((DateTime)entry.getColumnValues().get(17)).toJavaDate())

or

account.setDateExpiry1(((DateTime)entry.getColumnValue("Column Name")).toJavaDate());

If I get the document I would use something like this.

item = doc.getFirstItem("DateApproved");
account.setDateExpiry1(((DateTime)item.getDateTimeValue()).toJavaDate());

or

account.setDateExpiry1(((DateTime)doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray("DateApproved").get(0)).toJavaDate());

**Setting**

With Dates you have to create a Notes DateTime object.

So something like

Date tmpDate =(Date)account.getDateCompleted();
doc.replaceItemValue("dateCompleted", (DateTime)Session.createDateTime((Date) tmpDate));

Similar concepts apply to Name Fields etc, however, there does not appear to be an easy way or direct 'java' replacement for the XPages upload and download attachment controls. You need a solid understanding of the more advance techniques in Java on this. I have struggled but I do need to revisit it. There are some examples on this forum. The same applies to Rich Text, my understanding is you need to become fully conversant with MIME - which I am not.

Comment: Two remarks: when you need to write data back it is easier and as fast to just get the document. Your date code is bleeding memory since a dateTime object gets instantiated and not recycled

Comment: Many thanks for that snippet, does it still apply if you are using ODA? And in the case where you are accessing hundreds of documents, say recreating a View it would be better using View Entries and Columns for performance, is that correct?

Comment: It depends. Generally reading summary data (view columns) is faster than opening individual documents. However views also take storage - so if you have lots of columns your database grows rapidly. Views don't give you access to RichText, Mime, Attachments or the ability to update. I keep my views lean.

Answer (score 1):

If you want so save yourself a lot of headaches, deploy the OpenNTF Domino API (ODA). It takes care of recycling, provides proper Java collections, allows for easy extraction of MIME and JSON. 
There's an intro on openntf.org and you find some YouTube videos on it. Or head to Paul's for more info: http://www.intec.co.uk/ibm-connect-2017/

Comment: this is not an option for me at the moment :-(

Comment: It is always an option. If your admin has an issue deploying an OSGi plugin, let him/her talk to the friendly folks at OpenNTF. We sort it out